# iOS log file generated in test builds

Tags: ios, xcode8, cfnetwork, app-transport-security

I have created test build and performance testing team has found log file named like  **bundleid date.log** in the application folder. It contains App transport security exception in it. I noticed the CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS is disabled in xcode. Will this log file get generated on release build for app store submission?

Comment: What do you mean it is disabled.  You have it set to 0?

Comment: @wottle Its not been set in the code as well as environment variables in xcode

Answer (score 0):

The issue was some third party framework in project generate this log file. I opened a ticket with third party vendor to disable generating log files.